# Xamarin / Monotouch - NuGet -RequireConsent error

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a Xamarin 2 solution that's been working fine - but it suddenly won't build using Xamarin Studio for Mac. (It builds fine using Visual Studio)

This is the build error:

> /Source/trunk/c1/.nuget/NuGet.targets: Error: Command 'mono
>   --runtime=v4.0.30319 Source/trunk/c1/.nuget/NuGet.exe install "" -source ""   -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/Source/trunk/c1/"' exited with code: 1. (c1.Models)

I'm using this Add-in to restore Nuget packages within Xamarin Studio for Mac. All of the Nuget packages are downloaded and restored.
https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin

This article mentions a similar problem, but I've removed the space as it suggests and it hasn't made a difference. http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3332

I would greatly appreciate any tips - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You hit just one of the typical NuGet/xbuild compatibility issues, including the one I reported a while ago,

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic?field=CreationDate&direction=Descending&issuesToDisplay=All&keywords=xbuild&emailSubscribedItemsOnly=false

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4051

The workaround you find like using the latest NuGet.targets can help, but ultimately Microsoft guys have implemented a brand new restore approach (which has been deployed already to all Microsoft platforms), now it is time to wait for Xamarin to catch up.

(Updated: Now you should use 

`mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 .nuget/NuGet.exe update /self
mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 .nuget/NuGet.exe restore my.sln`
 to restore packages.

More information can be found at [NuGet site](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore))

Comment: Lex, thanks - it's been almost a year and I'm having this problem again. (Xamarin v3) ... any chance you have any new insight?

Comment: Just updated the answer. Tested on both OS X and Fedora.

Comment: This worked for me - thank you so much. Once I ran the command to "update -self" everything started building again in Xamarin. Another thing I noticed is that newer projects in Xamarin had a different version of files in the .nuget folder. So I guess this could have been also solved by creating a new project. This was much easier - THANKS!

Comment: For project files (such as .csproj), you need to remove their reference to `nuget.targets`, like I did in #SNMP, https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/commit/3e8b79b1f72f275ea05fd536103b591158685f10 In that way you don't need to recreate them from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved this problem. I replaced the NuGet.targets file with the following:

https://raw.github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Mobile/master/.nuget/NuGet.targets

That file seems like a more modern file that fixes some of the -RequireConsent and $(SolutionDir) spacing issues. I lost many hours on this - hope it helps someone else.

Comment: I'm curious... did you still have the same problem with Xamarin 3? (my question was originally about Xamarin 2)

Comment: Yes, I had just upgraded to Xamarin 3 beforehand.